# Does CF3COOH undergo decarboxylation ? Why or why not?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request

> Does $\ce{CF3COOH}$ undergo decarboxylation ? Why or why not?

**Attempt:**

I feel it should decarboxylate because $\ce{CF3-}$ carbanion must be stable due to fluorine's -I (electron withdrawing) effect  , but I am not sure.

Comment: That's reported in the literature, but the inductive effect still doesn't mean it's very favorable from a kinetic standpoint.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE!  Homework questions are okay but must demonstrate an attempt to solve/understand the question. Please note that formulas can be better expressed with \$\ce{}\$ for chemical formulas/equations, \$\mathrm{}\$ for math term/equations, and \$\pu\$ for units.  Also, take a minute to look over the [help center](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) to better understand our guidelines and question policies.

Comment: @Abcd There really is no point adding the word attempt to the question body. If it is an attempt at solving the problem, that should be fairly obvious...